# Discord.PY + SQLITE3 [Вывод значения в чат]

Tags: sqlite3, discord.py

Мне нужно выводить значение из таблицы в чат, но я не знаю как это сделать, может кто нибудь знает,и подскажет? Вот код:

```
@client.command(name="skill")
async def __sk(ctx):
    ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
        description=f"""{cursor.execute("SELECT (?) FROM users WHERE id = (?)".format(strenght, ctx.author.id))}"""
    ))
```

Если вы поторопитесь сказать что у меня код говно, или что то такое, то я новичок в таком, так что тут нету ничего удивительного)

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(name="skill")
async def __sk(ctx):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT {strenght} FROM users WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}")
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in records:
        strenght = row[0]
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=strenght))
```

Comment: Тогда уж: `cursor.execute(f"SELECT {strenght} FROM users WHERE id = ?", [ctx.author.id])`

Comment: исправил..............

Comment: Ваше право, но считаю, что параметры в запрос лучше через binding передавать, чем формировать их в запрос :) Для целых чисел это еще ок, но в случаи строк или других питоничьих типов возникнут проблемы - драйвер базы сможет тип питона преобразовать в вид, что база поймет, а при самостоятельном формировании строки запроса в таком деле можно накосячить, поэтому лучше привыкать использовать биндинги :)

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'strenght' referenced before assignment || Вылазит ошибка(

Comment: Ну дк объявите её заранее